# how to get a scope variable from a "countdown" attribute of a timer directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm trying to access to a $scope variable from the countdown attribute of a timer directive.
More in depth i have this timer directive:

```
<timer interval="1000"  countdown="scadenza">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds</timer>
```

the variable 'scadenza' is defined in the relative controller of the view with the syntax $scadenza but the attribute is not able to access to the variable.

any ideas?

Comment: What do you call **"field"**?

Comment: i'm sorry i mean variable

Comment: Can you put your code in plunker/jsfiddle and give the link??

Comment: Please show us how you try to access the variable and then we can help.

Comment: in the controller i've the following method:  $scope.offertaDelGiorno = function(){  
        offerteServices.offertaGiorno(function(offertaGiorno){
            $scope.scadenza= offertaGiorno.dataScadenza;           
        });  
    };                                                                             this method offertaDelGiorno is called in a ng-init directive in the div that contains the timer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `directive`, apart from `template` and `controller`, you can add one more object `scope`.

`scope` object defines which attributes of the `directive` will be mapped to the directive's scope.

So if you want the `countdown` variable in the scope of your directive... add this code in your `directive`'s declaration...

```
   ..... 
   template : "...",
   scope : {
     countdown : "="
   },
   controller : function
   .....
```

"=" says the countdown variable point to the reference of the scadenza. So if you make any changes in countdown variable in your directive.. those will be reflected in scadenza.

Now, you can access `countdown` variable in your directive's `$scope`.

Comment: ok but the angular timer directive is defined as following:               scope: {
                interval: '=interval',
                startTimeAttr: '=startTime',
                countdownattr: '=countdown'
            },                                                           i have to modify contdownattr??

Comment: why are u appending "attr" in scope object's variables... remove "attr"